# GitLab showing old commits every time a create a new MR

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using GitLab as versioning system. What I have observed is that, each time I create a new Merge Request (comparing my master with the upstream master repository) I can see in the history the previous commits of my older MRs, although the "Changes" are just empty:
[image]

I don't know if this is just an issue of the GitLab UI, as if I perform a diff between the upstream and my master, I can see nothing:

```
$ git diff upstream/master
<Nothing>
```

Do you have any clue? How can I get rid of old commits, if no change is detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` compares the code, while the MR looks at commit history.

It seems like your fork is not in sync with the upstream.

In your sandbox, use your favourite log tool that shows the log graphically, or do

```
git log --decorate --graph --format=oneline upstream/master master
```

you should see that `master` and `upstream/master` are not the same.

If `upstream/master` is currently in the state you want for `master` in your sandbox and your fork, which I assume is `origin/master`, you can use `git reset` to sync them. Here I assume `origin` is a private fork, and you don't care about the commits in it that are not also in `upstream`.

```
git fetch origin
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset upstream/master
git push -f origin master
```

At this point, any attempt to create a merge/pull request from your fork should tell you nothing needs to be merged.

EDIT: I added `-f` to `push`, and a note about which commits I assume you're willing to throw away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Indeed git.log showed some differences. I have used git reset to sync upstream with master, however I'm not able to push origin master:
`To gitlab.mw.xxxxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.mw.xxxxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`. Should I use `git pull origin` instead of `git fetch origin` ?

Comment: It depends. Is `origin` indeed your own private fork? And are the commits between `upstream/master` and `origin/master` of any value to you? If it's your private fork and don't care about those commits, you can throw them away by doing `git push -f origin master`. However, if the commits matter or it's a public repo, then you need to look at the history and sort it out more carefully. But as you wrote your initial question, I think `git push -f origin master` is what you want.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the commits in `origin` that are not in `upstream` do matter, you'll need a different workflow, to merge `upstream/master` into your sandbox's `master`, push that to `origin` and make a pull request from it. But as your question is written, I assume this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the kind support. I'll keep it as my default workflow to force sync between my fork and the upstream